# How to install extensions in contao 4.4

Tags: content-management-system, contao

I installed contao 4.4 in my localhost successfully.After successful installation I tried to install an extension via contao manager.Unfortunately it fails with console error.So I download zip file of extenson from [codefog](https://codefog.pl/extension/news-categories.html#tab-support)

and put it in the folder root/system/modules .But the extension is not found in backend.I think the extension is not installed successfully. How to make it works? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i install extensions in my contao 4 standard-edition. As commented, this only applies to the standard-edition, not the managed-edition. If you don't want to change to the standard-edition, you may better wait, until they fix the problem in the contao manager... Otherwise this is how it works:

**Installing a Contao 4 bundle**

*Info:* A bundle is the best thing you can find for extending contao.
It is the cleanest way of adding functionality to the contao cms.

1. Find the module on https://packagist.org/
2. Get the "require ..." command from under the title
3. Connect to your hosting (or if local, open cmd or terminal)
4. Change to the root of your hosting
5. Execute the require ... command for this extension

   `composer require madeyourday/contao-rocksolid-columns`
6. Add the module to AppKernel (File: app/AppKernel.php)
7. In the "$bundles" array we can now add our bundle to the list of bundles, that contao should load: (the bundle name used in this line can be found in vendor/%developer%/%extension%/src/ and then there is a ...Bundle... php File there, that tells you the name of the bundle)

   `new MadeYourDay\RockSolidColumns\RockSolidColumnsBundle(),`
8. Open the installtool of contao (contao/install) and update the database

**Installing a Contao 4 extension**

*Info:* A contao 4 extension is defined by it's developer, it is actually still the same method of programming like in 3.5 but someone has tested it in contao 4 and approved of its functionality. This is the second best thing you can find for extending contao.

1. Find the module on https://packagist.org/
2. Get the "require ..." command from under the title
3. Connect to your hosting (or if local, open cmd or terminal)
4. Change to the root of your hosting
5. Execute the require command for this extension

   `composer require heimrichhannot/dlh_googlemaps`
6. Add the module to AppKernel (File: app/AppKernel.php)
7. In the "$bundles" array we can now add our extension to the list of extensions, that contao should load:

   `new ContaoModuleBundle('dlh_googlemaps', $this->getRootDir()),`
8. Open the installtool of contao (contao/install) and update the database

**Installing a Contao 3.5 extension**

*Info:* A contao 3.5 extension is your last hope, it is the same code as in contao 3.5 may or may not work - you have to test it yourself.

1. Find the module on github (or some other repo)
2. Conntect to your hosting with ssh (or if local, just open cmd or terminal)
3. Change into "system/modules"
4. Download the repo (e.g. `git clone https://github.com/ContaoBlackForest/contao-system-notification system-notification`) - notice the added "system-notification" at the end, that should be the foldername, in which the extions has to be (you can find the folder in the composer.json file inside the extension under "Resources/contao")
5. Create syslinks (`bin/console contao:symlinks`)
6. Add the module to AppKernel (File: app/AppKernel.php)
7. This line should be added once, just after "use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;" (this only has to be added once and only if you are using contao 3.5 extensions)

   `use Contao\CoreBundle\HttpKernel\Bundle\ContaoModuleBundle;`
8. In the "$bundles" array we can now add our extension to the list of extensions, that contao should load:

   `new ContaoModuleBundle('system-notification', $this->getRootDir()),`
9. Open the installtool of contao (contao/install) and update the database

**Your Question**
To awnser your question, as the module you want to install, is a contao 4 extension, you could use the according instructions from above.

contao 4 extension - https://packagist.org/packages/codefog/contao-news_categories

Comment: The bundle you are referring to is not the same as codefog/contao-news_categories. Furthermore, your instructions only apply to the contao/standard-edition (just in case anyone wants to try this with the contao/managed-edition).

Comment: File: app/AppKernel.php is not found in my instance.Can I manually create this file?

Comment: No, if you do not have the file `app/AppKernel.php` you are probably using the `contao/managed-edition`. In that case, simply install the extension via composer and open the Contao Install Tool afterwards.

Comment: yeah.So How can I fix the compatibility of an extension in contao 4.4???

Comment: @Aswathy S What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Rory what do you mean by "until they fix the problem in the contao manager"? What problem are you referring to?

Comment: @fritzmg Well i think the contao manager can't handle the hosting Aswathy is using or the extension he wants to install. But users using the managed edition depend on it working and in this case it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Aswathy Can you send a printscreen of the contao manager Error? at the bottom of the page, i belive you can "show more details" and there you probably will see what's wrong

Comment: @Rory yeah it seems I misread the original post - I missed that there were errors. However it's a local development environment, not a remote hosting.

Comment: @fritzmg I downloaded custom_module extension from codefog.The extension is currently working with contao 3.x . How can I fix the compatibility of the extension so that the extension is perfectly working with the contao managed edition

Comment: You already asked that here: https://community.contao.org/en/showthread.php?23710-Migration-of-extensions-from-contao-3-to-contao-4 And as already said there, in general any Contao 3 extension is compatible with Contao 4 - with a few exceptions depending on specific API changes.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to install this extension manually. Simply run

```
composer require codefog/contao-news_categories
```

in the root folder of your Contao installation. Depending on how you installed composer the command might be different.